# React Native: Make sure an external app is running in the background

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, spotify

I want to make sure an external app on the phone (say Spotify) is open in the background without me having to manually open it and make it appear in the foreground (using intents or links).

I'm making an app that uses the Spotify API with React Native.
I read in another thread that you can not implement a [Web Playback](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) for React Native so I'm stuck with using the API.

My problem is that in order to use the phone as a playback device **you need the Spotify app running in the background**. Now I have a solution, use [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) and make the app open in the foreground. But that way I make the users leave my app, and somehow I have to tell them to come back which sounds like a terrible design. I also tried nesting the links into each other (first being Spotify the second being my app), it worked a few times but it is pretty unreliable.

So my question would be if **there's any way to call an external app and open it WITHOUT having it take foreground over my app**.

I'm pretty new with React Native so I'm still learning, but I would appreciate your guidance on this issue

Comment: Opening an app pretty much by default opens them in the foreground, unless they have a service or broadcast you can launch instead.  But no, there's no general way to make to make an app run in the background.  Of course you shouldn't need to-  whatever API you're using shouldn't need the app running, or if it does it should be communicating with a Service it owns.

Comment: Yeah, looking at their native AP (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/#play-a-playlist)I, the app doesn't need to be running.  It will make a service connection to a service in their app.  Doing so will run that service.  What youy may need to do is make a native module to bridge from js to java to use that api

Comment: Yeah, I think @GabeSechan answered the question.